# Show that polynomial of degree 3 with no x^2 is a subspace of P3

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello there Mathematics community,

Im puzzled why this linear algebra question is asking to show that  the absence of $x^2$ still allows the polynomial to be in the subspace.

Wouldn't I just check three conditions. How would removing $x^2$ affect the proof that this polynomial in in the subspace?

(1) Is the zero vector in the polynomial

(2) additivity

(3) Scalar multiplication

Thanks

Comment: Yes, just check those conditions. Does the $0$ polynomial have no $x^2$ term? What happens if you add two polynomials with no $x^2$ term? What if you multiply one by a scalar?

Comment: yes you would, and it wouldn't

Comment: You could also say that your set consists of all linear combinations of $1$, $x$, and $x^3$. These form a subspace of dimension $3$ of the vector space $P_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $p(x)=0$ certainly doesn't have a quadratic term
2. It is not possible to create an $x^2$ term by multiplying a bunch of constant, linear or cubic terms by some constant, nor is it possible to get an $x^2$ term by adding cubic, linear or constant terms together, as $x^2$ is orthogonal to each of these subspaces.